# How should look relationship database for chat app?

Tags: database

I have to create simplest possible message app. Im using NOsql database, but I have to create diagram with relaions for my classes. Is that correct way?
https://i.gyazo.com/0d9a1020aeea5b28ddd98856529262c8.png

Comment: How would we know without some requirements defined?

Comment: So this is as simple as on screen. I have only Sender, Receiver, msg(content + date). User in mailbox should see received messages. Thats all